# Swift closure with variable causing memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I am debugging my program with a memory leak issue.
In the ViewController, when it is pop out, the deinit function should be called. But it didnt, so I try to figure it out with the following step.

by commenting many lines, I found that the following lines make the ViewController didnt dealloc.

```
var api:APIGetList = APIGetList(tripId: trip.id, offsetToken: offsetToken,shouldRemoveAll:self.shouldRemoveAll)
api.request({ (obj, error) -> Void in
    //ingore here
    }, immediateHandler: {[unowned self](obj) -> Void in
        if var tripPosts = obj as? [TripPost]{
            self.tripPosts = tripPosts<--- this line cause the leak
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }, failHandler: { (errCode, errMsg, error) -> Void in
        self.isLoading = false
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
})
```

in my ViewController, I will call the api to get data, and replace the current tripPosts list. the line I mentioned as "this line cause the leak", when I comment it, the deinit called. So I think this line is the cause of the problem.

for the call back object - obj. It comes from the following codes:

```
var tripPosts = [TripPost]()
tripPosts = TripPost.MR_findAll()
immediateHandler(obj: tripPosts)
```

so what cause the memory leak??

Comment: im not sure if `unowned` is the right use here, have you tried using `[weak self]`?

Comment: @Fonix thanks for quick response, I have try unowned, weak, and none. Still no luck:(

Answer (score 4):

Try putting [weak self]  soon after the api.request({ in

```
  var api:APIGetList = APIGetList(tripId: trip.id, offsetToken: offsetToken,shouldRemoveAll:self.shouldRemoveAll)

        api.request({ [weak self](obj, error) -> Void in
            //ingore here
            }, immediateHandler: {[weak self](obj) -> Void in
                if var tripPosts = obj as? [TripPost]{
                    self.tripPosts = tripPosts<--- this line cause the leak
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }, failHandler: {[weak self] (errCode, errMsg, error) -> Void in
                self.isLoading = false
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        })
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but would you mind indicate where to put the [weak self]?

Answer (score 2):

oh... finally I figure it out. The problem is the line
self.tableView.reloadData()<--
and in the cellForTableView I assigned a delegate to cells which is not a weak reference...

so that's is not related to the closure